# How to have no data labels in PHPWord Charts?

Tags: phpword

I've been learning PHPWord and am impressed but have run into an unlikely problem.  It seems you're required to have Data Labels on all PHPWord chart points.  There are style options for chart objects to have data label positions ('categoryLabelPosition' and 'valueLabelPosition') of 'low', 'high' or 'nextTo' but that's it.  I would have expected 'none' as an option but it's not documented; and I've tried it and it causes error.

I can't find anything in the documentation that provides for having no data labels on chart points.
The data labels provided are very nice with small numbers of data points, but with larger numbers of data points charts become too busy, and eventually illegible.  Does anyone know of a way, w/o hacking the code, to achieve no data labels on PHPWord charts?  Thanks.

(Note - sample code is at https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/develop/samples/Sample_32_Chart.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
Just find the file Chart.php and change  
showVal and  showCatName to false
  */
    private $dataLabelOptions = array(
        'showVal'          => false, // value
        'showCatName'      => false, // category name
        'showLegendKey'    => false, //show the cart legend
        'showSerName'      => false, // series name
        'showPercent'      => false,
        'showLeaderLines'  => false,
        'showBubbleSize'   => false,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this Chart:

```
    $chart= new Chart(
        'column',
        $series,
        $categories,
        $barChartStyle
    );
```

You can actually do something like this:

```
$chart->getStyle()->setDataLabelOptions(['showCatName'=>false]);
```

or you could set it from the style array:

```
$barChartStyle=['dataLabelOptions'=>['showCatName'=>false]];
```

make sure to set the array before you initialize the Chart.